# How to work with types that change under composition?

Tags: haskell, arrows, type-level-computation

I recently read the very interesting paper [Monotonicity Types](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/231867/files/monotonicity-types.pdf) in which a new HM-language is described that keeps track of monotonicity across operations, so that the programmer does not have to do this manually (and fail at compile-time when a non-monotonic operation is passed to something that requires one).

I was thinking that it probably would be possible to model this in Haskell, since the `sfun`s that the paper describes seem to be 'just another Arrow instance', so I set out to create a very small POC.

However, I came across the problem that there are, simply put, four kinds of 'tonicities' (for lack of a better term): monotonic, antitonic, constant (which is both) and unknown (which is neither), which can turn into one-another under composition or application:

When two 'tonic functions' are applied, the resulting tonic function's tonicity ought to be the most specific one that matches both types ('Qualifier Contraction; Figure 7' in the paper):

- if both are constant tonicity, the result should be constant.
- if both are monotonic, the result should be monotonic
- if both are antitonic, the result should be antitonic
- if one is constant and the other monotonic, the result should be monotonic
- if one is constant and the other antitonic, the result should be antitonic
- if one is monotonic and one antitonic, the result should be unknown.
- if either is unknown, the result is unknown.

When two 'tonic functions' are composed, the resulting tonic function's tonicity might flip ('Qualifier Composition; Figure 6' in the paper):

- if both are constant tonicity, the result should be constant.
- if both are monotonic, the result should be monotonic
- if both are antitonic, the result should be monotonic
- if one is monotonic and one antitonic, the result should be antitonic.
- if either is unknown, the result is unknown.

I have a problem to properly express this (the relationship between tonicities, and how 'tonic functions' will compose) in Haskell's types.
My latest attempt looks like this, using GADTs, Type Families, DataKinds and a slew of other type-level programming constructs:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, AllowAmbiguousTypes, UndecidableInstances, KindSignatures, DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies #-}
module Main2 where

import qualified Control.Category
import Control.Category (Category, (>>>), (<<<))

import qualified Control.Arrow
import Control.Arrow (Arrow, (***), first)


main :: IO ()
main =
  putStrLn "Hi!"

data Tonic t a b where
  Tonic :: Tonicity t => (a -> b) -> Tonic t a b
  Tonic2 :: (TCR t1 t2) ~ t3 => Tonic t1 a b -> Tonic t2 b c -> Tonic t3 a c

data Monotonic = Monotonic
data Antitonic = Antitonic
class Tonicity t

instance Tonicity Monotonic
instance Tonicity Antitonic

type family TCR (t1 :: k) (t2 :: k) :: k where
  TCR Monotonic Antitonic = Antitonic
  TCR Antitonic Monotonic = Antitonic
  TCR t t = Monotonic


--- But now how to define instances for Control.Category and Control.Arrow?
```

I have the feeling I am greatly overcomplicating things. Another attempt I had introduced

```hs
class (Tonicity a, Tonicity b) => TonicCompose a b where
  type TonicComposeResult a b :: *
```

but it is not possible to use `TonicComposeResult` in the instance declaration of e.g. `Control.Category` ("illegal type synonym family application in instance").

---

What am I missing? How can this concept properly be expressed in type-safe code?

Comment: I think this has to be re-thought. `Tonic t :: * -> * -> *` has the right kind for `Arrow` or `Category`, but `Tonic Antitonic` is not a category since the composition of two (antitonic) arrows is no longer an (antitonic) arrow. Indeed, antitonic functions do not make a category. At best, we can make a category with "functions of known tonicity", using a type which does _not_ expose the tonicity (a sort of existential type) and juggle between `Tonicity t a b` (not a category) and `SomeTonicity a b` (category). Alternatively, we could use a `IndexedCategory` class to allow for tonicity changes.

Comment: @chi very interesting! Can you elaborate on how a `IndexedCategory` class would work?

Comment: Something like `class IC k where type F k t1 t2 ; type B k ; comp :: k t1 a b -> k t2 b c -> k (F k t1 t2) a c ; id :: k (B k) a c`, I guess, forcing `k` to define the composition rule for indices `t`s (and the index for `id`). This is untested, it might require some more changes.

Comment: @chi The other option you mention, is that similar to moving between GHC.TypeLits' `KnownNat n` and `SomeNat`?

Comment: Roughly, yes. I'd rather use two types instead of a typeclass like `KnownNat`, but the spirit is similar. This is assuming that you really want/need to reuse the standard arrow/category class,

Comment: @chi actually, this makes me think. `Arrow`s were first introduced as generalization of Monads because there were instances of them whose type specifications did not completely match up. Is there a more general `Arrow`-like interface waiting from the shadows that might be useful for cases like these, where the return type of composition might fill in a different `t`?

Comment: I believe there might indeed be such a generalization, extending `IC` above to arrows. Anyway, many standard typeclasses over the years have been extended/generalized in the libraries, but only a few of such generalizations proved useful enough to become widespread. This however does not mean that one should not experiment and have some fun ;)

Comment: @chi Very cool! So we have (a) change between a general (non-category) type and more specialized types that are not parametrized by `t` (but can also not compose in the same way because they are restricted categories?). (b) convert between a general and an existential type that does not expose `t`, but then there is no way to convert back. (Is this true?). (c) Usage of an IndexedCategory. Exactly how this would solve the problem I don't know yet, because I'd think that would hit the same limits as my attempt above(?) (Please post an answer!) or (d) hand-roll a more general Category and Arrow.

Comment: The code I finally ended up with (with a simpler example that working with tonicities) can be found [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/Qqwy/ebb6b8968817428f4f2a39fc3b59c57c). It is based on the answer by Li-Yao Xia, and also contains the helper 'indexed category' and 'indexed arrow' typeclasses suggested by @chi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The universe of tonicities is fixed, so a single data type would be more accurate. The data constructors are lifted to the type level with the `DataKinds` extension.

```
data Tonicity = Monotone | Antitone | Constant | Unknown
```

Then, I would use a newtype to represent tonic functions:

```
newtype Sfun (t :: Tonicity) a b = UnsafeMkSfun { applySfun :: a -> b }
```

To ensure safety, the constructor must be hidden by default. But users of such a Haskell EDSL would most likely want to wrap their own functions in it. Tagging the name of the constructor with "unsafe" is a nice compromise to enable that use case.

Function composition literally behaves as function composition, with some extra type-level information.

```
composeSfun :: Sfun t1 b c -> Sfun t2 a b -> Sfun (ComposeTonicity t1 t2) a c
composeSfun (UnsafeMkSfun f) (UnsafeMkSfun g) = UnsafeMkSfun (f . g)

-- Composition of tonicity annotations
type family ComposeTonicity (t1 :: Tonicity) (t2 :: Tonicity) :: Tonicity where
  ComposeTonicity Monotone Monotone = Monotone
  ComposeTonicity Monotone Antitone = Antitone
  ...
  ComposeTonicity _ _ = Unknown  -- Any case we forget is Unknown by default.
                                 -- In a way, that's some extra safety.
```

Comment: Nothing unsafe about `applySfun`! Might also be worth just reusing `Tagged`.

Comment: Very good point! I still think  `Sfun` should be its own opaque type though, while I think the point of `Tagged` is to be transparent.