# How to define a polyvariadic arrow?

Tags: haskell, arrows

This question is somewhat related to [this earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001863/how-to-work-with-types-that-change-under-composition):

I am trying to define a couple of semi-dependent types, which allow you to track the 'monotonicity' of functions (as described in the [Monotonicity Types](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/231867/files/monotonicity-types.pdf) paper), so that the programmer does not have to do this manually (and fail at compile-time when a non-monotonic operation is passed to something that requires one).

More generally: I'd like to keep track of some 'qualifiers' of a function

Based on [answers to this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001863/how-to-work-with-types-that-change-under-composition), I have been able to define an 'indexed category' and 'indexed arrow' where the qualifiers of `h` in `h = f >>> g` depend on the qualifiers of `f` and `g`.

This works well, as long as you only work with single-argument functions. However, (and normal arrows also have this problem), when you try to create an arrow with multiple arguments, you have the following options. (Using `(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int` as example):

1. Plain `arr (+)`. The result type of this will be `Arrow x => x Int (Int -> Int)`, since the function is curried. This means that only the first parameter is lifted into the arrow context, since the arrow 'returns a function with one parameter less'. In other words: The arrow context is not used for the rest of the arguments, so that's not what we want.
2. `arr (uncurry (+))`. The result type of this will be `Arrow x => x (Int, Int) Int`. Now both parameters have become part of the arrow, but we lose the ability to e.g. partially apply it. It also is not clear to me how to do uncurrying in an arity-independent way: What if we want three, four, five, ...-parameter functions?

I know it is possible to define a 'recursive typeclass' to create a polyvariadic function, such as for instance described on Rosettacode [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Haskell). I have tried to define a more general function-wrapping type that might work that way, but I have not managed to do so far. I have no idea how to properly discern in the typeclass instance for `a -> b` whether `b` is the final result or another function `(b' -> c)`, and how to extract and use the qualifier of `b'` if it turns out to be the second case.

Is this possible? Am I missing something here? Or am I completely on the wrong track and is there another way to lift an *n-argument* function into an arrow, regardless of the value of *n*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can define `arrowfy` to turn a function `a -> b -> ...` into an arrow `` a `r` b `r` ... `` (where `r :: Type -> Type -> Type` is your arrow type), and a function `uncurry_` to turn a function into one with a single tuple argument `(a, (b, ...)) -> z` (which can then be lifted to an arbitrary arrow with `arr :: (u -> v) -> r u v`).

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE
    AllowAmbiguousTypes,
    FlexibleContexts,
    FlexibleInstances,
    MultiParamTypeClasses,
    UndecidableInstances,
    TypeApplications
  #-}

import Control.Category hiding ((.), id)
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Kind (Type)
```

Both approaches use a multiparameter type class with overlapping instances. One instance for functions, which will be selected as long as the initial type is a function type, and one instance for the base case, which will be selected as soon as it's not a function type.

```hs
-- Turn (a -> (b -> (c -> ...))) into (a `r` (b `r` (c `r` ...)))
class Arrowfy (r :: Type -> Type -> Type) x y where
  arrowfy :: x -> y

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (Arrow r, Arrowfy r b z, y ~ r a z) => Arrowfy r (a -> b) y where
  arrowfy f = arr (arrowfy @r @b @z . f)

instance (x ~ y) => Arrowfy r x y where
  arrowfy = id
```

#### Side note about `arrowfy @r @b @z` syntax

This is TypeApplications syntax, available since GHC 8.0.

The type of arrowfy is:

```hs
arrowfy :: forall r x y. Arrowfy r x y => x -> y
```

The problem is that r is ambiguous: in an expression, the context can only determine x and y, and this doesn't necessarily restrict r.
The @r annotation allows us to explicitly specialize arrowfy.
Note that the type arguments of arrowfy must occur in a fixed order:

```hs
arrowfy :: forall r x y. ...

arrowfy @r1 @b @z             -- r = r1, x = b, y = z
```

([GHC user guide on `TypeApplications`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeApplications))

---

Now, for example, if you have an arrow `(:->)`, you can write this to turn it into an arrow:

```
test :: Int :-> (Int :-> Int)
test = arrowfy (+)
```

For `uncurry_`, there is a small additional trick so that n-argument functions are turned into functions on n-tuple, rather than (n+1)-tuples capped by a unit which you would get naively. Both instances are now indexed by function types, and what is actually being tested is whether the result type is a function.

```hs
-- Turn (a -> (b -> (c -> ... (... -> z) ...))) into ((a, (b, (c, ...))) -> z)
class Uncurry x y z where
  uncurry_ :: x -> y -> z

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (Uncurry (b -> c) yb z, y ~ (a, yb)) => Uncurry (a -> b -> c) y z where
  uncurry_ f (a, yb) = uncurry_ (f a) yb

instance (a ~ y, b ~ z) => Uncurry (a -> b) y z where
  uncurry_ = id
```

Some examples:

```hs
testUncurry :: (Int, Int) -> Int
testUncurry = uncurry_ (+)

-- combined with arr
testUncurry2 :: (Int, (Int, (Int, Int))) :-> Int
testUncurry2 = arr (uncurry_ (\a b c d -> a + b + c + d))
```

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/c754f2fd6a514d66559b92469e373352

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Can you explain what the `@`s mean in the line `arrowfy f = arr (arrowfy @r @b @z . f)` ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a note about typeapplications.

Comment: Related side-question: Is it correct to assume that it is impossible to implement something like this without overlapping instances, because we have to check if `b` in `a -> b` is another function or not? Or are there ways around this?

Comment: Yes to decide whether a type is a function type or not, you need overlapping type class or type family instances in general. But for a less general situation, this is not necessary if you know that there are only a finite number of possible constructors at the root. The other approach I personally prefer is to explicitly annotate the number of arrows to "lift" through, so you would have `arrowfy @2 (+) :: r Int (r Int Int)` above, but you could also write `arrowfy @1 (+) :: r Int (Int -> Int)` as well. This also avoids overlapping instances.